# Associating a unique session id with every unique user in asp.net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

How can I get unique session ID for every unique user who logs in ?? I'm using asp.net/c#

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Could you expand a little more on your question? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Dave I have webpage lets say 1.aspx and user x logs into that and selects some items and places them in shopping cart. Now there is user y who logs into 1.aspx and he can see the shopping cart selected by user x. So what I want to do is associate a unique session ID for every unique user who logs in so that shopping carts don't mingle up. So I thought unique sessionID might help in disassociating shopping carts depending on the users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.Net provides Session functionality - and many objects provide access to SessionID

This is quite sophisticated and can be used across multiple machines in a webfarm if needed.

See:

- ASP.NET Session State Overview - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx
- SessionID - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx

For logged in users, it might also be worth looking at:

- Introduction to membership - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx